# How to merge javascript object containing symbols?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, merge, lodash

I'm trying to merge two objects with lodash merge, but it doesn't work with symbols. Is there any alternative utility?

```
    import {merge} from 'lodash';
    import {Op} from 'sequelize';

    const selectA = {
        where: {
            text: "something"
        }
    };

    const selectB = {
        where: {
            date_from: {
                [Op.lt]: Sequelize.literal('NOW()')
            }
        }
    };

    console.log(_.merge(selectA, selectB));
```

Output:

```
{ where: { text: 'something', date_from: {} } }
```

Comment: not aware of sequalize but can you add the "date_from" to selectA Object, if it works for sequelize. selectA.where.date_from = { [Op.lt]: Sequelize.literal('NOW()') }

Comment: No, I can't. I want to do it programatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `_.mergeWith()` and supply a merge function that uses spread.

**Note**: look at the browser's console. The snippet's console doesn't display symbols.

```js
const Op = {
  lt: Symbol('symbol')
}

const selectA = {
  num: 15,
  where: {
    text: "something"
  }
};

const selectB = {
  num: 30,
  where: {
    date_from: {
      [Op.lt]: 'symbol value'
    }
  }
};

const result = _.mergeWith(selectA, selectB, (a, b) => {
  if (!_.isObject(b)) return b;
  
  return Array.isArray(a) ? [...a, ...b] : { ...a, ...b }
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cool, that works! Could you please explain why this consumes the symbols and the other one (simple merge) does not?

Comment: Because internally merge uses a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop (via the [`_.keysIn()`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/keysIn.js)) function) to iterate the objects, and for...in ignore  symbols. Shallow copying via spread also includes symbols, so we replace the default shallow merge of `_.mergeWith()` with our own function, while keeping the ability to deep merge.

Comment: Oh, I see, make sense. I just noticed that this merge doesn't work with numbers somehow. Try it with `const selectA = { my_bool: false }` and `const selectB = { num: 123 }` replaced. I'm getting `{ my_bool: false, num: {} }` (missing number) in the merge result.

Comment: It's a very naive implementation of a merging function. You can expand it to identify primitives and assign them instead of merging, and handle other types of objects. Look at the source code of `_.merge()`, and see how many cases it handles.

Comment: But symbol is the primitive type. How could it consume symbols but still run in the `_.merge()` way with other stuff?

Comment: Symbol as key, and not as value.

Comment: Anyhow, I've added a simple way to handle primitives. However, you'll probably need to handle other edge cases.

Comment: Okay, one more question. What is the difference now between your implementation with `_.mergeWith()` and simple destructuring assignment `{ ...a, ...b }`? Thanks for the updates.

Comment: If it's not object (arrays are objects as well) take the 2nd value. This will handle primitives.

Answer (score 1):

Use deepmerge instead of lodash
https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try that one with symbols, but it might do the job. I also find [merge-options] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-options) pkg, but don't want to add more and more pkgs.

Comment: I've tried deepmerge with symbols, and it works, and recommend it, because it is small and has not other dependencies, we all hate to include many node_modules, but as I see above there is decision with lodash, so it is better to stay with it :)